# VBA Code to Save As .XLSM

Tags: excel, vba

Need assistance to add command to save as .xlsm :-

```
Private Sub cmdSaveForm1_Click()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    'Create a default file name by concatenating the file name without the extention _
        plus the current date and time, and plus the xlsm extention
    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh mm") & ".xlsm"

    'Open Save As dialog to a default folder with default file name
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "P:\EU Funds Management - Treasury\TRS3_Abstract of Payments\TRS3_Authorisation_L1\" & Filename
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To save a Workbook as `.xlsm` you need the following file format

> Excel 2007-2010 Macro-Enabled Workbook (.xlsm) - 52 - xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

To save a file to an chosen format you need to specify the appropriate format when saving. This can be done by adding `FileFormat:=` to your save action.

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Below the addition of the save action and `FileFormat` to your code.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveForm1_Click()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    'Create a default file name by concatenating the file name without the extention _
        plus the current date and time, and plus the xlsm extention
    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh mm") & ".xlsm"

    'Open Save As dialog to a default folder with default file name
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "P:\EU Funds Management - Treasury\TRS3_Abstract of Payments\TRS3_Authorisation_L1\" & Filename
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

        If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub

        'get selected folder path from FileDialog, but remove filename from FileDialog
        folderPath = Left(strFolder, InStrRev(strFolder, "\"))

        'Save this workbook in chosen file path & appropriate filename
        'File format .xlsm
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Something went wrong.  It still prompted Save as type (*.xlsx)

Comment: @AlbertZahra the file is forcibly saved as `.xlsm`, the prompt has no specification at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Different Fileformats for excel are:

.xlsx = 51 '(52 for Mac)

.xlsm = 52 '(53 for Mac)

.xlsb = 50 '(51 for Mac)

.xls = 56 '(57 for Mac)

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=52   '=.xlsm in Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:
**.FilterIndex = 2**
**1 = xlsx, 2 = xlsm**

```
Private Sub cmdSaveForm1_Click()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    'Create a default file name by concatenating the file name without the extention _
        plus the current date and time, and plus the xlsm extention
    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh mm") & ".xlsm"

    'Open Save As dialog to a default folder with default file name
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .FilterIndex = 2  '2 = xlsm
        .InitialFileName = "P:\EU Funds Management - Treasury\TRS3_Abstract of Payments\TRS3_Authorisation_L1\" & Filename
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this always the case for excel workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SAVE_WORKBOOK()
    Dim ThisFile As String, newFile As String 'Variable definition.
    ThisFile = Range("A10").Value 'Get file name from cell.
    'Adding today's date in file name:
    newFile = ThisFile & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    ChDir _
    "C:\BACKUP" 'Naming the file path to save
    'Saving the file as xlsm:
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFile & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```

For example, if Cell `A10` is written Frain and today's date is `09.11.2024` the file name would be Frain `09-11-2023`.