# Only save as macro-enabled file

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to force only two formats to save files in via VBA?

So when I save a file the only formats that must be possible is .xlsm and .xltm

This is what I got so far, but it won't save the file:

```
If SaveAsUI <> False Then
Cancel = True
xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, fileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm, Excel Macro-Enabled Template (*.xltm), *.xltm")

If xFileName <> "False" Then
```

Comment: Possible? In code? sure...  in general? no.

Comment: @braX i added some code i found, the only thing I need is to save the file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733454/vba-code-to-save-as-xlsm